# Move backwards in regex pattern during next search

Tags: python, regex, string, regular-language

I have data in following pattern:

```
abc@1.0 name='abc'
abc@1.0 dep= {
"this",
"that",
}
abc@1.0 someInfo = "blahblah"
abc@2.0 name='abc'
abc@2.0 dep= {
"this",
"that",
}
abc@2.0 someInfo = "blahblah"
abc@3.0 name='abc'
abc@3.0 dep= {
"this",
"that",
}
abc@3.0 someInfo = "blahblah"
```

The objective is to find all records for each component@version (e.g. abc@1.0). I found multiple ways to solve this problem and they are working fine. However, during this process I could not solve this using one specific regex logic.

Here is what I tried:

(1) Removed all newlines

(2) regex pattern `(abc@.+?)(abc@|$)`

The problem is this will only get the alternative record as we have used the next 'abc@' in our regex pattern.

I am trying to find a way to move back in the string before I perform next regex search. i.e. I want to get all records not only alternative.

Please note that I am not looking for solution - I already solved this issue. I want to know how can we move back in string before performing next regex search.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @sln, Regex Pattern I was looking for: `(?s)abc@(?:(?!abc@).)*`

Comment: Where does a record begin and end?

Comment: Use something like `(?s)abc@(?:(?!abc@).)*` to partition records.

Comment: @sln Thanks, your second comment is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Though you said, you already have a solution, this is the one I came up with. In general, you can only go backwards with a [**backtracking control verb**](http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) but this is not really needed here.

---

You have two possible value constellations, one with `"..."` and one with `{...}` while the latter includes several other values. Additionally, you only want to have the values of a specific needle. Have a look at this code ([**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/WwD2BA) and the [**regex part on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/1sbdOB/1))

```
import re

string = your_string_here

def getResults(needle=None):
    """ Analyze the outer structure """
    # outer regex
    rx = re.compile(re.escape(needle) + r'''    # escape the needle to look for
        \s*
        (?P<key>\w+)                            # the key
        \s*=\s*
        (?:
            (['"])(?P<value>.+?(?!\\))\2        # a single value
            |
            \{(?P<values>[^{}]+)\}              # multiple values in {}
        )''', re.VERBOSE)

    def parseInnerValues(values=None):
        """ Parse the inner values """
        # inner regex
        rxi = re.compile(r'''(["'])(.+?)(?<!\\)\1''')
        return [m.group(2) for m in rxi.finditer(values)]

    def getValues(match=None):
        """ Decide """
        if match.group('values'):
            return parseInnerValues(match.group('values'))
        else:
            return match.group('value')

    matches = {match.group('key') : getValues(match)
                for match in rx.finditer(string)
                }
    return matches

print(getResults('abc@2.0'))
# {'dep': ['this', 'that'], 'someInfo': 'blahblah', 'name': 'abc'}
```